# jQuery append li generates new content on page but new link does not respond

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add a li to a list with jquery.  When the user accepts a pending invitation, the invitation's status is set to confirmed in the db, it is deleted from the "pending invitations" list on the page, and it appears in a separate UL below.  All of this is working fine except the link in the newly-created li does not work.  Or, rather, it works in terms of the deleting the item from the database, but it does not disappear from the screen.  If I reload the page, it is gone.  Here's my code:

**teams_controller.erb:**

```
      def myteams
    action = params[:command]

    if (action == "accept")
      @invite = TeamUser.find(params[:id])
      @invite.confirmed = true
      @invite.save
      @newteam = @invite
    end

    if (action == "delete")
      @invite = TeamUser.find(params[:id])
      @team = Team.find(@invite.team_id)
      @invite.destroy
      if (@team.owner == current_user.id)
        @team.destroy
      end

    end

    @teams = current_user.teams

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.js
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
```

**myteams.js.erb:**

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@invite) %>').fadeOut(700);
<% if @newteam %>
 $('#acceptedList').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'teaminlist', :locals => {:invite => @newteam})%>");
<% end %>
```

**_teaminlist.html.erb:**

```
<li class='team' id='<%= dom_id(invite) %>' >
  <h3>
  <% if invite.team.owner == current_user.id%><i><% end %>
  <%=link_to invite.team.name, 
          :controller => 'teams', :action => 'show', :id => invite.team.id %></i>
  <%=link_to image_tag('delete.png'), 
          {:controller => 'teams', :action => 'myteams', :id => invite.id, :command => 'delete'},
          :class => 'deleteTeam', :remote => true %>
</h3></li>
```

**myteams.html.erb:**

```
<h3>My Teams</h3>
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


<p style='clear:both'></p><hr width='660'><BR>

<div class="post">
<h3 style="text-decoration:underline;">Pending Invitations:</h3>
<ul style="list-style-type:none; line-height:20pt;" id='inviteList'>
<% current_user.team_users.where("confirmed is null").order("created_at DESC").each do |invite|%>
  <li class='invite' id="<%= dom_id(invite) %>">
  <h3><%=link_to invite.team.name,
          :controller => "teams", :action => "show", :id => invite.team_id %>
  <%=link_to image_tag("checked.png", :size => "16x16"), 
          {:controller => "teams", :action => "myteams", :id =>invite.id, :command => "accept"}, 
          :class => "deleteTeam", :remote => true %>
  <%=link_to image_tag("delete.png"),
          {:controller => "teams", :action => "myteams", :id =>invite.id, :command => "delete"},
          :class => "deleteTeam", :remote => true %>
  </h3></li>
<% end %>
</ul>

<h3 style="text-decoration:underline;">My teams:</h3> <ul style='list-style-type: none; line-height:20pt;' id = 'acceptedList'>
<% current_user.team_users.where(:confirmed => true).order("created_at DESC").each do |invite| %>
  <li class='team' id="<%= dom_id(invite) %>" >
  <h3>
  <% if invite.team.owner == current_user.id%><i><% end %>
  <%=link_to invite.team.name, 
          :controller => "teams", :action => "show", :id => invite.team.id %></i>
  <%=link_to image_tag("delete.png"), 
          {:controller => "teams", :action => "myteams", :id => invite.id, :command => "delete"},
          :class => "deleteTeam", :remote => true %>
  </h3></li>
<% end %>

  </ul>

  <h3><center><%= link_to "Create a Team", new_team_path %></center></h3>
</div>
```

Once again, it is only the newly created li that does not respond when the "delete" icon is clicked.  The existing li's work fine.  Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't speak Ruby but it sounds to me you need to use [$.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because the element doesn't exist when the DOM is first loaded.

```
$('li.team').on('click', '.deleteTeam', function() {
     // and the peasants rejoice!?
});
```

> If you are on jquery version < 1.7.1 you should use:
>
> ```
> $('.deleteTeam').live('click', function() {
>      // and the peasants rejoice!?
> });
> ```

*credit [keviv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/935831/keviv) for acknowledging the little people.*

Comment: I suspect that you're right but the code you suggested is not working.  Do I have to pass ('#<%= dom_id(@invite) %>').fadeOut(700) in the curly braces?

Comment: If that's what the delete button is supposed to do, ya.  I should mention I've found `$.on()` to be a bit buggy, if it doesn't work with the example above, use `$(document)` in place of `$('li.team')`

Comment: `$(document).on('li.team', 'click', function() {})` is the most efficient way to do this and makes the most sense. Events bubble up to the document even if they're added after the DOM is loaded. Note this is jQuery 1.7. In 1.6, use `delegate()`.

Comment: I'm so confused.  Where would I put that binding?  In myteams.js.erb?  Nothing is working : (